# A question about the Spring-boot-starter-data-jpa

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

The Spring Boot Starter Data JPA dependency indeed have some good configs by default, it just picks the information from my application.properties, right?

Unfortunately, my project doesn't recognize its configurations. I'm forced to do a config class to run my project. My Eclipse don't show any `pom.xml` error either. In my `pom.xml`, I simply got this warning: The managed version is `2.0.2.RELEASE` The artifact is managed in `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.0.2.RELEASE`

Here's my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.jequiti</groupId>
<artifactId>Projeto</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>IntegraPedidos</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- JDBC -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-restdocs-mockmvc</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<!-- Repository for ORACLE JDBC Driver -->
<repositories>
    <!-- Repository for ORACLE JDBC Driver -->
    <repository>
        <id>codelds</id>
        <url>https://code.lds.org/nexus/content/groups/main-repo</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And this is my properties file:

```
#===============================
#JPA / HIBERNATE
#===============================
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use following properties to make spring data jpa work as expected.

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = none
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql = true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql = true
```

Setting `ddl-auto = none` will not change your database schema even if your Mapped Entity class has changed. It is not recommended to use `none` unless you are really sure what you are trying to achieve.

Setting `show_sql = true` will log the sql statements executed by hibernate.

Setting `format_sql = true` will format the sql statement logs into more readable form. However, it is not necessary step in order to get logs printed.. it is just for readability.

Comment: Oops, I'm sorry about this: I forgot to add my complete properties here, I didn't notice until now
I will update my post

Comment: Are you following any tutorial for this?

Comment: Actually I simply created a new project on Spring Initializr with Starter-JPA, Starter-JBDC, and Rest. Since the beginning, I followed various tips and tutorials, and my project can't run without a config file ( I saw an example here on Stack).

Comment: That's all is in your properties file?? (you posted above in question) If so, try removing last 2 line from your properties file.. rebuild the project. and then run... see if it works..!!